# Is disabling CORS on map tiles service security risk?

Tags: web-mapping, tiles, web-service, security, cors

I would like to know what security issues or security risk would prevent disabling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on map tiles service.

Most of public tiles services, such OSM, Google, Bing or ESRI, have CORS enabled.

What could be the security risk to disable CORS for a map tiles service?

Comment: I think it's the other way around: you prevent security issues or security risks by **enabling** Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

Comment: @GermánCarrillo How? The answer I got from the provider his, we dont enable it because of security issue.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo enabling CORS does allow manipulating image with different origin, disabling CORS prevent it, am I correct?

Comment: That's what I understand. See [Why do we need CORS](http://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2015/django-cors.html). However, I'm not an expert on the topic; let's see what experts say about it. :D